# Set directory for related imports while using importlib.import_module

Tags: python, python-import

Assume I have the following project structure

```
core (dir)
  __init__.py
  settings.py
main.py
```

In my program I'm downloading additional repo and unpacking it to the subdirectory in the root directory:

```
additional_prj (dir)
  trails (dir)
    static (dir)
      __init__.py
  core (dir)
    __init__.py
    settings.py
```

After these actions my project workdir is

```
core (dir)
  __init__.py
  settings.py
main.py

additional_prj (dir)
  trails (dir)
    static (dir)
      __init__.py
  core (dir)
    __init__.py
    settings.py
```

In `additional_prj.trails.static.__init__.py` I have function `fetch()`, which I want to import and use dynamically. The shorten content of this file is:

```py
from core.settings import UNICODE_ENCODING

def fetch():
  pass
```

So in `main.py` I have the following code

```py
import sys
import importlib

sys.path.append(str(pathlib.Path.cwd() / 'additional_prj'))
module = importlib.import_module('trails.static')
result = module.fetch()
```

The problem with that is while executing `module = importlib.import_module('trails.static')` Python executes  `from core.settings import UNICODE_ENCODING` using root `core/setting.py` but not `additional_prj/core/settings.py`.

I have tried to `add sys.path.remove(str(pathlib.Path.cwd()))` before importing but it hasn't worked. How to set the path for additional imports during dynamic import?